# Why can't I call protected virtual base class function in the derived class overridden function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Base
{
protected:
    virtual void show()
    {
        // Do some stuff.
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    virtual void show()
    {
        // Do some stuff.
    }
};

class Derived_2 : public Derived
{
protected:
    virtual void show()
    {
        this->show();    // error: Base::show() is in accessible
        show();          // error: Base::show() is in accessible
        Derived::show(); // error: Base::show() is in accessible
    }
};
```

In above case calling virtual base class function (overridden in derived classes) gives an error.

Comment: Looks fine to me (although your stack will overflow). What is your compiler?

Comment: It works [perfectly fine](http://ideone.com/GtVImL).

Comment: Are you sure your inheritance (in your actual code) is public and not private?

Comment: yes I just pest the code sample from code but I removed namespaces here the Base class in another namespace and use (using namespace namespace_name) looking it my code once again because If I removed namespace it works fine.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, works, `Derived_2::show` leads to infinite recursion...

Comment: I found the problem.
It is because of namespace collision as the show() function is locked in some where in namespace for which I have written (using namespace namespace_name;) and that class is also derived.
Thanks to all of you.

Comment: `using namespace` in my opinion is sheer devilry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I can find, is that you call `show` from itsel leading to infinite recursion and ending in a stack overflow error.

But this code compiles and run without even a warning :

```
class Derived_2 : public Derived
{
public:
    virtual void show()
    {
        //this->show();    // infinite recursion => stack overflow
        Base::show();    // ok calls show() from Base
        Derived::show();    // ok calls show() from Derived
        std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

(I declared it public to call it directly in my test)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct and you want to call `Base::show()` then you may do that by with:

`Derived::Base::show();` or just `Base::show();`

But if you just want to call super class's method you have a correct code.